# Get the IP address of GeoServer from WPS

Tags: geoserver, wfs, java, wps

I am creating a custom WPS process. The process needs to do WFS and REST requests to the same server (GeoServer). Currently, the client needs to provide the IP and port of the server as a parameter.

Is there any way inside the WPS process code I can get the server IP and port?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that there is a "fix" built in for that, just refer to the layer as coming from:

```
xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs"
```

and GeoServer will do the right thing. So a complete input block would look like:

```
<wps:Input>
  <ows:Identifier>first</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
    <wps:Body>
      <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp">
        <wfs:Query typeName="topp:states"/>
      </wfs:GetFeature>
    </wps:Body>
  </wps:Reference>
</wps:Input>
```